# PHP/Javascript - Start/Stop Counter on admin side

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating a form based on multiple choices. While students go for the test, the counter will start at the top of the page. The counter is relative to number of questions selected by the user.

**Example:** If the user had selected 20 questions and the interval is 1 minute per question - then the counter will run up to 20 minutes, which means for 1200 seconds.

This is the code for user side counter:

```
<input type="hidden" name="que" id="que" value="<?php echo $_POST['no_que']?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="toggle" id="toggle"/>
<form method="post" action="result_test.php">
<input type="hidden" id="no_que" name="no_que" value="<?php $_POST['no_que']?>"/>
<table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="center">
<span id="countdown" class="timer" style="font-size:xx-large"></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<div id="countdowndiv" class="timer"></div>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
include('connection.php');
$sql="select class_id from class where class_name='".$_REQUEST['class']."'";
$query=mysql_query($sql) or die("query failed".mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$class_id=$row['class_id'];
$sql1="select subject_id from subject where subject_name='".$_REQUEST['subject']."'";
$query1=mysql_query($sql1) or die("query failed".mysql_error());
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
$subject_id=$row1['subject_id'];
$sql2="select * from test where class_id='$class_id' and subject_id='$subject_id' and chapter>='".$_REQUEST['chapter1']."' and chapter<='".$_REQUEST['chapter2']."' ORDER BY     RAND() LIMIT 0,100";
$query2=mysql_query($sql2) or die("query failed".mysql_error());
while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($query2))
{
?>
<input type="hidden" name="hf" id="hf" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['no_que']?>"/>
<tr>
<td>
<label name="<?php echo $row2['id']?>"><?php echo $row2['question']?></label><br>
<input type="radio" name="option<?php echo $row2['id'] ?>" id="option1" value="1"/><?php echo $row2['option_1']?>
<input type="radio" name="option<?php echo $row2['id'] ?>" id="option2" value="2"/><?php echo $row2['option_2']?>
<input type="radio" name="option<?php echo $row2['id'] ?>" id="option3" value="3"/><?php echo $row2['option_3']?>
<input type="radio" name="option<?php echo $row2['id'] ?>" id="option4" value="4"/><?php echo $row2['option_4']?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}
}
?>
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="2">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And this is the JavaScript for the timer:

```
//script for timer start
var no_que=document.getElementById('que').value;
var get_seconds=no_que*60;
var MAX_COUNTER = get_seconds;
var time_interval=get_seconds/12;
var counter = null;
var counter_interval = null;
var temp;
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
    setCookie(name,"",-1);
}

function resetCounter() {
    counter = MAX_COUNTER;
}

function stopCounter() {
    window.clearInterval(counter_interval);
    deleteCookie('counter');
}

function updateCounter() {
    var msg = '';
    if (counter > 0) {
        counter -= 1;
        msg = counter;
        setCookie('counter', counter, 1);
    }
    else {
        msg = "Counting finished.";
        stopCounter();
    }
    var el = document.getElementById('countdown');
    if (el) {
        el.innerHTML = msg;
        document.getElementById('toggle').value=msg;
        if(msg==get_seconds)
        {
        document.getElementById('countdowndiv').innerHTML = "<img src='images/12.png' width='100px' height='100px'/>";
        }
        if(msg>=(get_seconds-time_interval) && msg<get_seconds)
        {
        document.getElementById('countdowndiv').innerHTML = "<img src='images/11.png' width='100px' height='100px'/>";
        }
        if(msg>=(get_seconds-(time_interval*2)) && msg<(get_seconds-time_interval))
        {
        document.getElementById('countdowndiv').innerHTML = "<img src='images/10.png' width='100px' height='100px'/>";
        }
        if(msg>=(get_seconds-(time_interval*3)) && msg<(get_seconds-(time_interval*2)))
        {
        document.getElementById('countdowndiv').innerHTML = "<img src='images/9.png' width='100px' height='100px'/>";
        }
        if(msg>=(get_seconds-(time_interval*4)) && msg<(get_seconds-(time_interval*3)))
        {
        document.getElementById('countdowndiv').innerHTML = "<img src='images/8.png' width='100px' height='100px'/>";
        }
        if(msg>=(get_seconds-(time_interval*5)) && msg<(get_seconds-(time_interval*4)))
        {
        document.getElementById('countdowndiv').innerHTML = "<img src='images/7.png' width='100px' height='100px'/>";
        }
        if(msg>=(get_seconds-(time_interval*6)) && msg<(get_seconds-(time_interval*5)))
        {
        document.getElementById('countdowndiv').innerHTML = "<img src='images/6.png' width='100px' height='100px'/>";
        }
        if(msg>=(get_seconds-(time_interval*7)) && msg<(get_seconds-(time_interval*6)))
        {
        document.getElementById('countdowndiv').innerHTML = "<img src='images/5.png' width='100px' height='100px'/>";
        }
        if(msg>=(get_seconds-(time_interval*8)) && msg<(get_seconds-(time_interval*7)))
        {
        document.getElementById('countdowndiv').innerHTML = "<img src='images/4.png' width='100px' height='100px'/>";
        }
        if(msg>=(get_seconds-(time_interval*9)) && msg<(get_seconds-(time_interval*8)))
        {
        document.getElementById('countdowndiv').innerHTML = "<img src='images/3.png' width='100px' height='100px'/>";
        }
        if(msg>=(get_seconds-(time_interval*10)) && msg<(get_seconds-(time_interval*9)))
        {
        document.getElementById('countdowndiv').innerHTML = "<img src='images/2.png' width='100px' height='100px'/>";
        }
        if(msg>=(get_seconds-(time_interval*11)) && msg<(get_seconds-(time_interval*10)))
        {
        document.getElementById('countdowndiv').innerHTML = "<img src='images/1.png' width='100px' height='100px'/>";
        }
        if(msg<(get_seconds-(time_interval*12)))
        {
        document.getElementById('countdowndiv').innerHTML = "<img src='images/0.png' width='100px' height='100px'/>";
        }
    }
}

function startCounter() {
    stopCounter();
    counter_interval = window.setInterval(updateCounter, 1000);
}

function init(temp) {
    if(!temp)
    {
    counter = getCookie('counter');
    }
    else
    {
    counter=temp;
    }
    if (!counter) {
        resetCounter();
    }
    startCounter();
}

init();

/*toggle function start*/
function toggleoff()
{
window.clearInterval(counter_interval);
deleteCookie('counter');
}
function toggleon(temp)
{
init(temp);
}
/*toggle function end*/
//script for timer end
```

Now, the problem is that there are 2 buttons to toggle the counter on and off on the admin page. The first button is *Start* and the second button is *Stop*. Now, when an admin clicks on the *Start* button, the counter should start and when they click on the *Stop* button, the counter should stop.

I have tried many things without luck, because my admin page is in **admin** -folder.

So, can anyone suggest me a solution on how to get the value of `"<input type="hidden" name="togggle" id="toggle" />"` declared in above user side PHP file, to the admin side page, because this hidden field contains the counter value.

Comment: As a general suggestion, try to identify the core of your problem and make a small demo and paste here only that part instead of putting here the whole file. It will help people understand faster your problem and it will increase your chances to get a good answer.

Comment: and maybe this is an error, you sometimes have "toggle" with 2 g and sometimes with 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to do an ajax query?. I think you can use jQuery and check with ajax which button has been pressed in admin panel and then you can program what to do in the success function. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

When any button will be pressed in admin, you should stored it (maybe in a file or maybe in database)

Answer (score 3):

You could take one of two approaches.

Either you poll from the client and ask the server what state you should be in, or you could use something like web sockets.  Either way your admin panel will store its start stop state somewhere.

**Polling**
With polling, you make requests to a server every x number of seconds to request the current state you should be in.  In your case where seconds matter it might be quite demanding if multiple people were taking a test and all polling every second.  You could take an alternative approach and use long polling which you can read about in many places.

**Web sockets**
Web sockets, if you are using modern browsers, would be ideal.  They would allow you to push information to the client from the server as soon as the state changes, without the need for the client to keep asking.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter where the files are loaded from. You have access to the hidden input field in the DOM, like any other input in the page.

```
//if you can do this:
var no_que=document.getElementById('que').value;

// then you also can do do this.
var t = document.getElementById('toggle');
// do whatever with t.value
```

Comment: everybody is making the assumption that these 2 pieces of html and js are in 2 different places? When I see some HTML and some JS and no doctype or file I assume that they can be together as well

Comment: friend as u said in above code, i have written that in javascript file,but it fetches the value from user side page not an admin side.

Comment: forget about admin side. Is called server side. You have client side where your JS lives and does stuff and then you have server side where the dynamic app, in this case the PHP can modify stuff. Although dynamic, right now you are not executing the PHP part more than once, so you are only generating the a value fot the toggle element once. If the PHP can change this variable you have to decide how it will be changed and how the client side (JS) will be informed by this change. This is called designing your program. Before doing a lot of code, do this first: think on how your app should work.

Comment: @ElzoValugi why do you assume he means server side when he says admin?  If admin have a start/stop button then I think it would be safer to assume that the admin panel is another client side panel for administrative users that can start/stop everyone elses timers.  Yes there will be server side code but I don't believe the admin = server.